# Parse: Session Not Created on Login

Tags: session, authentication, parse-platform

I'm having a slight issue when using the `logIn` class method. According to the docs, I should see a Session automatically created when a user logs in successfully.

> Sessions are automatically created when users log in or sign up. They
>   are automatically deleted when users log out.

I'm logging in successfully, and am returning a success message to the console.

```
$("#login").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var name = $("#login-name").val();
  var pass = $("#login-password").val();

  Parse.User.logIn(name, pass, {
    success: function(user) {
      console.log("Logged in successfully!");
    }, error: function(user, error) {
      console.log("Login error: " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

But when I jump into the Parse.com Data Browser, I can't see the Session under the Data Tab.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Seem to have fixed this by enabling "Require Revocable Sessions" in the Parse.com app settings page.